# isomap and self intersections

Tags: smooth-manifolds, data-analysis, geometry

I sample a 2D surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $N$ points, and compute an isomap using pairwise weighted geodesic distances. I am thus able to embed this surface into a $M$ dimensional space in which pairwise euclidean distances closely match their respective weighted geodesic distances on the original manifold. In brief, I just perform a standard isomap, solved with the SMACOF procedure.

However, I am wondering if this approach can lead to a self-intersecting manifold. If so, does increasing the dimensionality $M$ of the target space guarantee that at some point their won't be any intersection remaining ? Otherwise, how can I prevent self intersections from happening ?

Comment: You can avoid self-intersections by working in a higher dimension. Take a look at the Whitney embedding theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem

Comment: thanks! But do you know if, in the specific case of isomaps, increasing the dimension would avoid self-intersections in the same way as it does with Whitney's trick ?

Comment: What's an isomap?

Comment: it is a multidimensional scaling (MDS) using geodesic distances as input. And MDS is a technique which tries to recover a set of N dimensional points whose pairwise euclidean distances closely match a given distance matrix. If this given distance matrix is also euclidean, the result can be computed using a PCA, otherwise we can rely on the SMACOF technique which is an iterative procedure.

Comment: What is SMACOF? What is PCA? Why do you expect people to know this jargon? And by the way, MDS is a heuristic to solve an essentially intractable problem...

Comment: PCA is a principal component analysis, a technique very very well known in statistics - maybe as famous as singular value decomposition. SMACOF is also a rather common technique for solving MDS problems, and MDS is also a very common problem in statistics. Isomap is a special case of MDS which is well known in computational geometry. I expect at least some people to know about these concepts : I was told that research questions are for MathOverflow while scholar questions are for math.stackexchange. What do you call a heuristic ? There are many theorems, bounds, algorithms etc. related to MDS.

Comment: (for example, some bounds for embedding using these techniques : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/papers/07.BRS.local-dim-REVISED.pdf )